# Converting Hansen Global Forest Change 'Forest Loss Year' into panel data structure

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing, panel, rstudio

I downloaded the hansen deforestation loss year layer from the website (https://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.7.html).

It is a single raster with one band. Pixels that weren't deforested have a value 0 and deforested pixels have the year of deforestation. I have since joined this data to other datasets and exported this to work with it as a df in R.

For my analysis I need a panel structure. However, I'm confused about how to achieve this e.g. if a pixel was deforested in 2001, would I need it to appear again in the data for every year other than 2001 with a value 0?

I'm unsure about this because it assumes in the 'loss year' dataset there is no record of deforestation happening more than once in each cell. Because it's a single band raster it seems this must be the case but I can't find any information to confirm this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on your most pressing issue.

Comment: *Would I need it to appear again in the data for every year other than 2001 with a value 0?* It makes sense. It is like 'Dummy Variable Encoding' in machine learning.